# Minimal syntax highlighting for Tex File, with only math expressions, section-structures and begin/end{environment}

Tags: vim, latex, vim-syntax-highlighting, latex-suite

My Vim is *very slow* at rendering the syntax highlighting of LaTeX documents using the default syntax file to be found in `c:\vim\vim80\syntax\tex.vim`. The problem is partially solved in this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1111109/vim-slow-at-rendering-the-buffer-with-latex-syntax-highlighting/1147337), yet it is hard to write LaTeX document with no visual clue. What is a good way to start writing a minimal syntax file by myself? 
By minimal, I am expecting to have:

1. Highlighting math expressions enclosed by `$`, `\[` and `\]`; also, those Tex specific commands like `\pi`.
2. Sections, usually in form of `\section{Section Name}` and `\subsection{Subsection Name}`.
3. Environments, usually in form:

   `\begin{environment}`

   `\end{environment}`

Comment: What you need is this: [`syntax.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html)

Comment: It might easier to make a copy of the existing syntax file and remove, one by one, the parts to don't need.